# Integrating FogBugz, what kind of API/integration points does it have?

Tags: .net, fogbugz

Other than logging into FogBugz and using it etc, what kind of integration points does it have?

Answer (score 5):

It has a pretty complete API: http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/docs/60/topics/advanced/API.html

Their are solutions for a lot of IDEs and you can integrate it with source control:
http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/Ecology.html

Answer (score 3):

There's a REST API that's documented [here](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/docs/60/topics/advanced/API.html). There's a fun tutorial [here](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/blog/post/An-API-Tutorial-Plus-Excel-2007-Export-Plus-Zombies!.aspx). If you find any issues, let us know. We want a complete API.

There's a bit of an [ecology](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/Ecology.html) that's grown up around this.  There's also [integration with many source code control systems](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/docs/60/topics/advanced/Sourcecontrolintegration.html).

**Forthcoming**:

There's a full plug-in architecture forthcoming in our next version.  Our developer alpha is just around the corner. If you're comfortable in a .NET language, particularly C# .NET, and have some thoughts about extending FogBugz, you can sign up to be included in the developer alpha [here](http://www.fogcreek.com/sendmail.html).

Answer (score 1):

See the [FogBugz API documentation](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/docs/60/topics/advanced/API.html).